# Where are the closed betas?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51

I was browsing proposals on Area 51.  All the proposals that have been in beta for over 70 days: "Will be launching very soon".  Is there a way to see proposals that have finished the beta (either launched or did not succeed)?

It would be nice to compare a proposal in beta to those ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the launched sites here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched

As for the failed sites, they aren't listed anywhere, but there are only two so far:

Gadgets: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets
AI: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence